# Why is my user prompt different than the current user logged in?

Tags: ldap

I am kinda stumped with this one.

I setup an OpenLDAP server for centralized login to all of the VM servers ... and a test VBOX Ubuntu Desktop.

Getting LDAP authentication to work was not terribly hard.

The thing I cannot figure out is why the server takes my login and allows me access but then bumps to the only unprivileged user on the box.

For example I have a machine (Ubuntu Desktop 11.04) with a user called `User`. When I login with my LDAP account as `ianc` it lets me but when I go to a prompt and type `whoami` it returns `User`.

What the heck is going on?

I thought I was logged in as `ianc`

The same thing happens on my file server which I setup the same test on.

I login and says I am `fs01` not ianc.

Help?

Oh yeah I got this picture of my test VBOX desktop

[image: Desktop]

Comment: Since the author found the solution can someone close this?

Comment: can you move your Update from the question to an answer please? Thank you!

Comment: It has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my user account overlapped with the local user account's UID, my UID was 1000 and the local user was 1000 once I changed it I am now represented correctly.